# Use undeclared type use CoreData Extension error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

Swift 2.3 / Xcode 7.3.1

Hi i'm create a Entity in Core data then create NSManagedObject class in Editor. (Objective - C)

After this i created Class and try use Entity as extension

```
    import Foundation

extension EntityTest {


}
```

But showed a error message "Use of undeclared type 'Entity Test'". In others entity works normally. Someone can explain for me why this occurs?

EDIT: Issue was resolved with simple add "#import "file.h" at bridging header for expose to Swift

Comment: Show the rest of your implementation...

Answer (score 0):

Now, Coredata automatically generate its entity as NSManagedObject.
It seems like a bug of Xcode.

So, to fix this, go to your xcdatamodeld file, select the entity make compile error, and select Core Data Inspector on the right side of your Xcode.

You can find drop box titled 'Codegen' in 'Class' section.

If you want to generate NSMsnagedObject file manually, set Codegen to Manual/None.

or, select Class Definition.

Now, save the file( this is important. ), and clean.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure you don't have any *.properties.swift files in your project .If you do, delete those and then to the Entity - Editor> Create NSManagedObject Subclass steps above

The *properties.swift files are left over in case you deleted them from xCode and just removed references to them. Xcode still sees those files, it does not create others to ovveride them and it errors out.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on the {Entity-Name}-CoreDataProperties.swift
- Click "Show in Finder"
- Drag the {Entity-Name}-CoreDataClass.swift file to your project
- Be sure to uncheck the "Copy Item if Needed"
- CMD-SHIFT-K to clean your project
- CMD-B to build your project

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Can happen when you forget to check "Is Initial View Controller"!